# Western Wall and Note Maintenance

Tags: eretz-yisrael, kotel-western-wall

How does Israel maintain the notes on the Western Wall? Clearly, if no one moved the notes they place in the wall than it would get completely filled so they must perform some note maintenance. However, these are notes to G-d I believe so it must be handled very delicately. Any insight?